# Invert icon color of status bar cordova

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, statusbar

I need to change the color of the icons and fonts of the status bar. As in the example of Soundcloud... I can change the background in white, but the icons are white and are not distinguished

[soundcloud statusbar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6cNt.jpg)

[my app status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVQfb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
.status-bar{
  background-color:white;
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: This is for the Android status bar, not for CSS.